# Why Maven generates a maven directory in a jar when two jars are merged?

Tags: maven, jar

I've merged sources from two artifacts/jars into separate single jar using assembly plugin. However, looking at the content of the new jar file at `META-INF/maven` there is a `maven` directory which contains packages from both of those jars.

[image]

**Few questions:**

1 - What is the purpose of that `META-INF/maven` dir?
2 - How/who generate that file and why?
3 - Is there an option to remove it from the archive and how?
4 - What is the impact if we removed it from the archive?

**Here is my plugin:**

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>merge-two-jars</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <finalName>com.ibm.scope.ext.system.agent-${scope.release}-${ibm.build.number}</finalName>
          <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
      <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/ppk-agent-merge-agent-common.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
          <archive>
              <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
              <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
```

.....

Comment: Please attach your `ppk-agent-merge-agent-common.xml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Informational purpose - maven feature
2. Maven for informational purpose
3. For JAR, EAR, and WAR Plugins. Use `<archive><addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor></archive>` to exclude `META-INF/maven`, [MWAR-27](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MWAR-27)
4. No impact

---

Overriding Manifest

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          [...]
          <archive>
             <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        [...]
      </plugin>
      [...]
</project>
```

More about Maven Manifest: [Maven Archiver](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, as mentioned in the question description, I'm using Assembly plugin to generate the jar; not maven.jar.plugin .... Any idea how we do it in the assembly?

Comment: override `archive` configuration in assembly plugin, answer updated, try this, should work

Comment: Updated `addMavenDescriptor` - to false, Maybe this is also needed to exclude manifest from merged jars

Comment: @Simple-Solution Why are you using maven-assembly-plugin to create jar ? Why not maven-jar-plugin? What is the purpose?

Comment: @khmarbaise *I've merged sources from two artifacts/jars into separate single jar*

Comment: @MariuszS - I've added the `<addMavenDescriptor>`, still not removing the dir.

Comment: Please attach your `ppk-agent-merge-agent-common.xml`